# How we can create Geolocation through AWS:cloudfromation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I have implemented this but it says invalid request. It may totally wrong.
I want to create geolocation for particular country

```
"Geolocation": {
  "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
  "Properties": {
    "HostedZoneName": {
      "Ref": "Route53Domain"
    },
    "Name": {
      "Fn::Join": [
        "$",
        [
          {
            "Ref": "javadns"
          },
          {
            "Ref": "Route53Domain"
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "Type": "CNAME",
    "TTL": "60",
    "GeoLocation": {"CountryCode" : "*"},  
    "ResourceRecords": [
      { "Fn::Join" : [".", ["geoip", { "Ref" : "javadns" }]]}
    ]
  }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a Geo Location record you must specify the [SetIdentifier property in CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html#cfn-route53-recordset-setidentifier).

i see you are missing that property in your CloudFormation and probably that is why it is throwing you an error.

Also here are the code countries identifiers that are supported by Route53, you must not specify the wildcard in that parameter, countries and continent codes consist of two letters.

[Documentation here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-geo.html#rrsets-values-geo-location)